# Self-test errors and kernel crashes in 11.1 when using the suggestions bar

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, crash, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 11.1 and fixed in 11.1.1**

Whenever the suggestions bar has an item with a pull-down menu of options
(that you get by clicking on the down-arrow), picking any of the options
results in an error message:

INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: EventTracker|c|521
Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
the Wolfram System by reporting it to Wolfram Research.

If I keep repeating this, the kernel crashes eventually fairly consistently.

This is on Windows 7 64 bit:

"11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"

Does anyone else have the same issue?

Comment: just disable the buggy suggestion bar

Comment: [**Don't leave the Suggestions Bar enabled**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/5478)

Comment: I know it is not a satisfactionary duplicate but it is really a question for WRI.

Comment: This is a FE bug introduced in 11.1. The Suggestion bar is one way to trigger it, but other attached cells (e.g. Image editor, mesh region assistant) are also affected. It will be fixed in 11.1.1.